# How do I avoid or work around the floor function and incorrectly represented integers?

Tags: javascript, rounding

So I am trying to take a number that can be in any positive form and cut it to two decimal places. So for example I have an input of 145.26. However in my code this is being rounded down to 145.19. Here is the code I am using:

```
        var multiplier = 100;
        var adjustedNum = input * multiplier;
        var truncatedNum = Math[adjustedNum < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](adjustedNum);
        var fixedResult =  truncatedNum / multiplier;
```

So basically my 'input' should become 145200. However it is actually becoming 145199.9999995 or something to that effect. This is causing the Math.floor method to round it down. Is there any way to workaround or avoid this?

Comment: Use `Math.round()` to change `145199.9999` to `145200`.

Comment: I don't want to do this because I need to keep the 2 decimal places exactly as they are. So 132.267 would change to 132.27 but I want it to stay as 132.26

Comment: Change multiplier to 1000.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not quite sure I follow how this would help

Comment: Multiply by 1000, round it, then divide by 10 and do your ceiling/floor decision.

Comment: Awesome seems to work now. Thanks. Want to turn it into an answer so you can get some credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the number by an additional factor of 10 to round it. Then divide it by 10 to apply the `floor` or `ceil`.

```
var multiplier = 100;
var adjustedNum = Math.round(input * multiplier * 10);
var truncatedNum = Math[adjustedNum < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](adjustedNum/10);
var fixedResult =  truncatedNum / multiplier;
```